# Calculate a total of values from a column when cells in another column contain a specific word

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to test a column to see if its cells contain a specific word. When that word is found I need the value in the 'G' column of the same row to be added to a total.  The main reason is the table im using will have additional entries over time so it will take extra work to change my =SUM ranges.  I want the summation to take place automatically.

Comment: It's unclear from your question - can you add some sample data and sample expected output? Do you perhaps need `SUMIFS()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just adding values from column G where column B meets a criteria, you need a `SUMIFS`. Copy the following into C1:

`=SUMIFS($G$1:G1,$B$1:B1,"Criteria")`

And copy that down. The result in column C is a running total of the values in G where B meets the criteria.

Comment: Yes this is what i needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this example, we are looking for the word **GOLD** in column **B** and maintaining the sum in column **C**.

In **C1** enter:

```
=IF(B1="GOLD",G1,0)
```

In **C2** enter:

```
=IF(B2="GOLD",G2+C1,C1)
```

and copy downward:

[image]

As you see, every time GOLD is found in column **B**, the accumulated sum is updated with the value found in column **G**.